# MySQL - UPDATE WHERE field IN query with LIMIT refused

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is there any way to do the following query in MySQL?

```
UPDATE url_source_wp
SET url_source_wp.hash = "ASDF"
WHERE url_source_wp.url IN (SELECT
                              url_source_wp.url
                            FROM url_source_wp
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN url_done_wp
                                ON url_source_wp.id = url_done_wp.url_source_wp AND url_done_wp.url_group = 4 AND
                                   hash IS NULL
                            WHERE url_done_wp.url_source_wp IS NULL
                            ORDER BY url_source_wp.id ASC
                            LIMIT 50);
```

There are two problems here:
MySQL does not support limit for subquery.
MySQL does not support updating a table which is used in the select.

Comment: Just use a temporary table to store the results of your subquery

Answer (score 0):

Now that it is properly formatted it looks like your subquery is independent so I really recommend using a temporary table. If you are hoping the results of your subquery will change you can batch your updates and still use a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE url_source_wp AS upd
  JOIN
    ( SELECT s.url
      FROM url_source_wp AS s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN url_done_wp AS d 
          ON  s.id = d.url_source_wp 
          AND d.url_group = 4
          AND hash IS NULL
      WHERE d.url_source_wp IS NULL
      ORDER BY s.id ASC
        LIMIT 50
    ) AS lim
    ON lim.url = upd.url
SET upd.hash = 'ASDF' ;
```